# Is there a better way to do this instead of using addClass/removeClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, addclass, removeclass

I'm looking for a less redundant way to this:

Basically, I have some buttons that toggle a change in appearance on a table. If you press the first button, the first column is selected. If you press the second, the second column and third are selected, and so on.

The method I have to do this is pretty ugly and seems really repetitive... but... it works? How can I improve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pkg-btn-sm").click(function() {
    $(".pkg-btn-md, .pkg-btn-lg").addClass("pkg-btn-off");
    $(".pkg-btn-sm").removeClass("pkg-btn-off");
    $(".pkg-1, .pkg tr td:nth-child(2)").addClass("pkg-1-active pkg-active");
    $(".pkg-1, .pkg tr td:nth-child(2)").removeClass("pkg-off");
    $(".pkg-2, .pkg tr td:nth-child(3), .pkg-3, .pkg tr td:nth-child(4), .pkg-4, .pkg tr td:nth-child(5), .pkg-5, .pkg tr td:nth-child(6)").addClass("pkg-off");
    $(".pkg-2, .pkg tr td:nth-child(3), .pkg-3, .pkg tr td:nth-child(4), .pkg-4, .pkg tr td:nth-child(5), .pkg-5, .pkg tr td:nth-child(6)").removeClass("pkg-active pkg-2-active pkg-3-active pkg-4-active pkg-5-active");
  });
  $(".pkg-btn-md").click(function() {
    $(".pkg-btn-sm, .pkg-btn-lg").addClass("pkg-btn-off");
    $(".pkg-btn-md").removeClass("pkg-btn-off");
    $(".pkg-2, .pkg tr td:nth-child(3)").addClass("pkg-2-active pkg-active");
    $(".pkg-3, .pkg tr td:nth-child(4)").addClass("pkg-3-active pkg-active");
    $(".pkg-2, .pkg tr td:nth-child(3), .pkg-3, .pkg tr td:nth-child(4)").removeClass("pkg-off");
    $(".pkg-1, .pkg tr td:nth-child(2), .pkg-4, .pkg tr td:nth-child(5), .pkg-5, .pkg tr td:nth-child(6)").addClass("pkg-off");
    $(".pkg-1, .pkg tr td:nth-child(2), .pkg-4, .pkg tr td:nth-child(5), .pkg-5, .pkg tr td:nth-child(6)").removeClass("pkg-active pkg-1-active pkg-4-active pkg-5-active");
  });
  $(".pkg-btn-lg").click(function() {
    $(".pkg-btn-sm, .pkg-btn-md").addClass("pkg-btn-off");
    $(".pkg-btn-lg").removeClass("pkg-btn-off");
    $(".pkg-4, .pkg tr td:nth-child(5)").addClass("pkg-4-active pkg-active");
    $(".pkg-5, .pkg tr td:nth-child(6)").addClass("pkg-5-active pkg-active");
    $(".pkg-5, .pkg tr td:nth-child(6), .pkg-4, .pkg tr td:nth-child(5)").removeClass("pkg-off");
    $(".pkg-1, .pkg tr td:nth-child(2), .pkg-2, .pkg tr td:nth-child(3), .pkg-3, .pkg tr td:nth-child(4)").addClass("pkg-off");
    $(".pkg-1, .pkg tr td:nth-child(2), .pkg-2, .pkg tr td:nth-child(3), .pkg-3, .pkg tr td:nth-child(4)").removeClass("pkg-active pkg-1-active pkg-2-active pkg-3-active");
  });
});
```

```css
.pkg-btn-sm,
.pkg-btn-md,
.pkg-btn-lg {
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.pkg-btn-sm:focus,
.pkg-btn-md:focus,
.pkg-btn-lg:focus,
.pkg-form input:focus,
.pkg-form select:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.pkg-btn-off,
.pkg-btn-lg:hover,
.pkg-btn-md:hover,
.pkg-btn-sm:hover {
  color: white;
}
.pkg-btn-sm {
  background: #f9bc1a;
}
.pkg-btn-sm:hover {
  background: #cc9403;
}
.pkg-btn-md {
  background: #00b3e2;
}
.pkg-btn-md:hover {
  background: #2bd4fe;
}
.pkg-btn-lg {
  background: #a10104;
}
.pkg-btn-lg:hover {
  background: #e70308;
}
.pkg-btn-off {
  background: #a8a8a8;
}
/* Center all text in the form */

.pkg th,
.pkg td,
.pkg-ch,
.pkg-ch:before {
  text-align: center;
}
/* Style column headings */

.pkg th {
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
/* Cell height and alignment */

.pkg td {
  height: 38px;
  vertical-align: center;
}
/* Check mark styling */

.pkg-ch:before {
  content: "\f00c";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 2px;
  position: relative;
}
/* Set the first column to a minimum width so it appears larger */

.pkg-ti-em {
  min-width: 200px;
}
/* The first column is always the title */

.pkg-ti,
.pkg tr td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: left !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
/* Every odd row's title cell should have this background color */

.pkg tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(1) {
  background: #f0f0e6;
}
/* Different color for even rows */

.pkg tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(1) {
  background: #e7e7db;
}
/* All even rows have a different background color*/

.pkg tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fafaf9;
}
/* The second column is the second package color, etc */

.pkg-active {
  color: white !important;
}
.pkg-off {
  color: #a8a8a8 !important;
}
.pkg-1,
.pkg-2,
.pkg-3,
.pkg-4,
.pkg-5 {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.pkg-1,
.pkg tr td:nth-child(2) {
  color: #f9bc1a;
}
.pkg-1-active {
  background: rgba(249, 188, 26, 0.5);
}
.pkg-2,
.pkg tr td:nth-child(3) {
  color: #cd9500;
}
.pkg-2-active {
  background: rgba(205, 149, 0, 0.5);
}
.pkg-3,
.pkg tr td:nth-child(4) {
  color: #00b3e2;
}
.pkg-3-active {
  background: rgba(0, 179, 226, 0.5);
}
.pkg-4,
.pkg tr td:nth-child(5) {
  color: #e70308;
}
.pkg-4-active {
  background: rgba(231, 3, 8, 0.5);
}
.pkg-5,
.pkg tr td:nth-child(6) {
  color: #a10104;
}
.pkg-5-active {
  background: rgba(161, 1, 4, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<link href="//www.myameriflex.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//www.myameriflex.com/bootstrap/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="w_mg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h4>How many employees do you have?</h4>
        <button class="pkg-btn-sm">1-19</button>
        <button class="pkg-btn-md">20-49</button>
        <button class="pkg-btn-lg">50+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="w_mg pkg_table">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <table class="pkg">
          <thead>
            <th class="pkg-ti-em col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="pkg-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">Focus</th>
            <th class="pkg-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">Impact</th>
            <th class="pkg-3 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">Boost</th>
            <th class="pkg-4 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">Advantage</th>
            <th class="pkg-5 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">Complete</th>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <td>FSA / HRA Option</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>HSA / LPSA Option</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ameriflex Guarantee</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Free MPC</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>DCA</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>CRA</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>COBRA</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Time &amp; Labor Management</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>ACA Compliance</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>HR Anwer Link</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>HR on Demand</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>POP Plan</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>POP Document Services</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Discrimination Services</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Form 5500</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Wrap Doc</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>SPD</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>SBC</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>HIPAA CCC</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Direct Billing</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Leave Management</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Payroll</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><i class="pkg-ch"></i></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opqz6n4L/)

I feel like the issue might also lend itself to how I have the table setup and created the classes. I'm not sure if I'd solve this with a loop, an array, an if statement... I'm kind of stumped.

I found other questions about addClass() and removeClass() but nothing about this in particular. I apologize if this has already been asked and I welcome any direction to where this has been answered or if it's a really simple solution that I missed!

Comment: Well for starters, once you've built a jQuery object for a particular selector, you shouldn't have to build it all over again for the next statement. That's what the jQuery chaining architecture is for.

Comment: Whoops. I'm not sure how I forgot about that, thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Pointy, you could chain your jQuery selectors so you don't need to type them over and over again.

The other thing you could do, is to simplify the classes that you need to add to toggle the states.

The javascript would look like the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".pkg-btn-sm").click(function() {
            $("th, td").addClass("pkg-off");
            $("th, td").removeClass("active");
            $(".pkg-btn-md, .pkg-btn-lg").addClass("pkg-btn-off");
            $(".pkg-btn-sm").removeClass("pkg-btn-off");
            $(".pkg-1, .pkg tr td:nth-child(2)").addClass("active").removeClass("pkg-off"); 
        });
        $(".pkg-btn-md").click(function() {
            $("th, td").addClass("pkg-off");
            $("th, td").removeClass("active");
            $(".pkg-btn-sm, .pkg-btn-lg").addClass("pkg-btn-off");
            $(".pkg-btn-md").removeClass("pkg-btn-off");
            $(".pkg-2, .pkg tr td:nth-child(3),.pkg-3, .pkg tr td:nth-child(4)").addClass("active").removeClass("pkg-off");

        });
        $(".pkg-btn-lg").click(function() {
            $("th, td").addClass("pkg-off");
            $("th, td").removeClass("active");
            $(".pkg-btn-sm, .pkg-btn-lg").addClass("pkg-btn-off");
            $(".pkg-btn-md").removeClass("pkg-btn-off");
            $(".pkg-4, .pkg tr td:nth-child(5),.pkg-5, .pkg tr td:nth-child(6)").addClass("active").removeClass("pkg-off");
        });
    });
```

And the following changes have to be applied to your CSS
Instead of:

```
.pkg-active
```

You write this:

```
th.active, td.active {
    color: white !important;
}
```

And furthermore instead of:

```
.pkg-1-active {
    background: rgba(249, 188, 26, 0.5);
}
```

you can write this

```
.pkg-1.active, td:nth-child(2).active {
    background: rgba(249,188,26,0.5);
}
```

This way, your code becomes at least a little bit more readable

To simplify your code even more and make it to some degree more generic you could add a btn-toggle class to your buttons as well as a data-attribute with the columns to toggle active. The javascript would then look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn-toggle").click(function() {
            $("th, td").addClass("pkg-off").removeClass("active");
            $("th:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(1)").removeClass("pkg-off")
            $(".btn-toggle").addClass("pkg-btn-off");
            $(this).removeClass("pkg-btn-off");
            var rowsToToggle = $(this).data("toggle").split(",");
            for (var i = 0; i < rowsToToggle.length; i++)
            {
                $(".pkg td:nth-child("+ rowsToToggle[i]+ "),.pkg th:nth-child("+ rowsToToggle[i]+ ")").addClass("active").removeClass("pkg-off"); 
            }
        });
    });
```

And in your CSS you would only use the nth-child() selectors.

Full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/brr8y0np/

Comment: @ViperCode your solution is even better though!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I knew there had to be a better way. I'm interested in what ViperCode comes up with, but I think this is a good start in the right direction!

Comment: So looking at this a little closer, this will make the labels column grey or "off" as well because you've added the off state there, too. How would I get around that?

Comment: You can change the code a litte to fix this. By adding $("th:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(1)").removeClass("pkg-off"); everything should work as you need it to. I edited the answer to incorporate this.

Comment: @Ame Klein I was hoping it was going to work out better, but form the docs on columns it doesn't look like it supports changing text color and it doesn't appear to be able to override row backgrounds. It's never as easy as it seems haha

Comment: @Arne Klein, I learned a ton from your answer! Thanks a bunch. I tested it in a [new fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/brr8y0np/3/) and it works great. Selected you as the answer, although ViperCode had a great idea!

Answer (score 2):

When you set up your table, you can use  to modify individual columns

```
<table class="pkg">
  <colgroup>
    <col span=1 class="labels">
    <col span=1 class="sml">
    <col span=2 class="med">
    <col span=2 class="lrg">
  </colgroup>
<!-- REST OF TABLE HERE -->
</table>
```

And then just add/remove classes to the col. I'll work on a Codepen for you right now.

Comment: I absolutely did not know you could do that! That is great, thank you for your help!

Comment: Honestly There was way too much for me to cleanup and change, but here's what I got so far. It should give you strong starting point! Be sure to accept an answer :) thanks!

Comment: So I'm just farting around here with the different solutions... [I tried this with yours](https://jsfiddle.net/koqa04nL/). It looks like doing this puts the column styling under everything else? I suppose I'd also have to use a description for each column, the way I did it with two on the second and third packages wouldn't let me style those separately... or am I missing something still?

Comment: The Fiddle looks the same as the original one posted.

Comment: Upon more research I found this out about columns: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns The background only applies if the background is already transparent and I don't see support for text color. That's a little disappointing considering how straight forward this initially seemed.

Comment: Well, darn. This was a great concept, I still learned something interesting that might be helpful otherwise,

Answer (score 1):

#### Some strategic use of classes should help you clean this up a lot.

1. You want to set up classes for columns in order to get rid of crazy jQuery selectors. It looks like ViperCode is helping with that.
2. Add a class (probably "pkg-btn") that your package buttons all share. You can then replace code like

   ```
   $(".pkg-btn-sm").click(function() {
       $(".pkg-btn-md, .pkg-btn-lg").addClass("pkg-btn-off");
       $(".pkg-btn-sm").removeClass("pkg-btn-off");
   }
   ```

   with something like

   ```
   $(".pkg-btn-sm").click(function() {
       $(".pkg-btn).addClass("pkg-btn-off");
       $(this).removeClass("pkg-btn-off");
   }
   ```

   which is then generic and can be factored out as a function so you just have

   ```
   $(".pkg-btn-sm").click(function() {
       selectPkgBtn(); // or whatever you called your function
   }
   ```

#### Don't forget you can chain jQuery commands.

```
$(".pkg-1, .pkg tr td:nth-child(2)").addClass("pkg-1-active pkg-active");
$(".pkg-1, .pkg tr td:nth-child(2)").removeClass("pkg-off");
```

can be refactored to

```
$(".pkg-1, .pkg tr td:nth-child(2)").addClass("pkg-1-active pkg-active").removeClass("pkg-off");
```

Comment: Definitely needs a lot of cleaning up on the classes... there are way too many overlapping classes

Comment: I realized this about halfway through the page... This is just a single page to add to a client's site and I already have more lines of CSS than their whole stylesheet. I think I'm missing something fundamental here... 

This is a very helpful answer, thank you very much!